# Meaning of "after the pips"

Tags: idioms, british-english, idiom-meaning

> For 100 years, the BBC has parceled up disaster and defeat, then distributed them, after the pips and before the weather forecast, to the British.

"After the pips" should be something similar to "before the weather forecast", if true, what is after the pips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"The pips" is the [Greenwich Time Signal](https://www.bbc.com/historyofthebbc/anniversaries/february/the-pips/) which is played on the radio just before the hourly BBC news broadcasts. It was intended to allow people to synchonise their timepieces to the national standard time. The weather forecast is given at the end of the news broadcast.

Therefore, "after the pips and before the weather forecast" represents the duration of the news broadcast itself.